# How can I Load Test an application that lives on a terminal server

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, terminal, load-testing

I have an application that lives on a Windows 2008 Terminal Server. Is there a way I can simulate a bunch of users, 100 for example, logging into the server, and then launching an executable?

The executable that will be launched is actually a test script that will handle starting the actual application and running through the test scenarios, so I only need the executable launched.

What options do I have available for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commercial Stress Test applications for RDP are around, but they're not free:

- http://www.scapatech.com/?page_id=79
- http://www.tevron.com/citratest.asp
- http://www.mercuryinteractive.com

There are also tools that shipped with W2k3 (I assume they're also around in W2k8). They were called [robosrv and robocli](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786809%28WS.10%29.aspx). Combine these with consume (to create an artificial bottleneck) and you should have some pretty good metrics.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I contacted one of the companies you mentioned, and am still waiting for a response. Regarding robosrv and robocli, I can't seem to be able to find them anywhere for Server2008. The only thing I've been able to find is that it's part of the 2003 resource kit, but those two executables weren't part of the download. Any thoughts on where I could get them, especially the 2008 versions?

Comment: It would appear that they're completely gone from Server 2008. I don't know if that's deliberate, or an oversight, but it's a pity.